# Does the creation of a subclass object create objects of its superclasses as well?

Tags: java, class, memory, object

Heres an example of what I mean:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    private int length;
    private int breadth;
    .
    .
}

public class Box extends Rectangle
{
    private int height;
    .
    .
}
```

When you:

```
Box b = new Box();
```

Does it create a Box as well as a Rectangle object, with the rectangle not directly accessible, but only accessible through the Box object. In other words, does it create two objects in memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **In other words, does it create two objects in memory?**

No, it creates a single object. This single object represents a `Box` (and since this is a subtype of `Rectangle` this same object represents a `Rectangle` as well).

The inheritance simply ensures that the interface of the `Box` object is an extension of the `Rectangle` interface.

Comment: Okay, but what I don't understand is that I was told Box doesn't inherit the private instance variables of Rectangle, but it can access them via public methods. In that case wouldn't there have to be a Rectangle object somewhere in memory? //Confused

Comment: @Zac Blaric: You were told wrong - Box *does* inherit these, it just can't access them directly.

Comment: @Zack Blazic, well, that's a matter of wording. You could also say that it inherits them but that it can't access them.

Comment: @Zac - related: [Does subclasses inherit private fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716040/does-subclasses-inherit-private-fields)