# Undestanding Java Inheritance: strange behaviour

Tags: java, inheritance

I don't understand a strange behavior of class inheritance.

This is my parent class:

```
public class Cubetti implements Token{
   ...
    private int id=1;
   ...
    public Cubetti(int n) {
        numero = n;
    }
   ...
    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId( int idx) { id = idx; }
   ...
}
```

and this is the subclass:

```
public class RGC extends Cubetti{
    private int id=0;
   ...
    public RGC (int idx) { 
        super(0);
        id = idx; // STRANGE BEHAVIOUR !
    }
   ...
}
```

This is the test mainclass:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        RGC uno = new RGC(1);
        RGC due = new RGC(2);

        System.out.println(" uno Id is  " + uno.getId() + " due Id is" + due.getId());

 }
```

The output is

> Uno Id is 1 and due Id is 1

but if I use in the tagged line on the `RGC` subclass:

```
....
// id = idx;
setId(idx);
....
```

The output is

> Uno Id is 1 and due Id is 2

Why?

Comment: because it is designed so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529901/inheritance-private-field-in-java

Comment: get to learn new things with java  and java concepts everyday. thanks for the question and btw its not a strange but the correct behaviour.

Comment: edit: wrong place for the comment

Answer (score 3):

You have an `id` variable in both the `Cubetti` super-class and `RGC` sub-class. Using the setter and getter updates/returns the `id` of the super-class, since those methods are defined in the super-class and are not overridden by the sub-class.

Calling `id = idx` in the sub-class constructor modifies the sub-class's variable, since the sub-class's variable hides the super-class's variable, and even if it didn't hide it, you wouldn't be able to access it from the sub-class, since it's private.

Comment: Ok. Probably i have to improve my concept of inheritance. I'm an old c programmer and i'm learning programming from zero again after some decades.. so be patient with me :)

Correct me if i'm in wrong: since now i've though a subclass as something that take a model from the parent class but have a sort of "formal" indipendence. Instead i have to think a subclass instance as formally a parent class instance with something more, so when i define a subclass behavior i have some stricts constraints, i can add some funcionality, but not a lot more

Comment: @IdoTraini A subclass may add state (variable) and behavior (methods) to those of the parent class. It can also override behavior (methods) of the parent class (assuming they are not private or package-private for a parent class located in a different package). It can't, however, override variables of the parent class. If it defines variables of the same name as in the parent class, it hides them.

Answer (score 0):

**In Java**::
private properties are not inherited to the derived class. So the `Cubetti`'s private property is not seen (directly accessible) in the scope of `RGC`'s class. `Cubetti`'s id property is only accessible through the outside world using the `get()` & `set()` methods (if these method are declared public).

**In the 1st case where your output is following:**

`Uno Id is 1 and due Id is 1`

The reason is that, the `Cubetti`'s `getId()` & `setId()` methods are inherited to the `RGC` class as they are public method of `Cubetti` class. So whenever you call the `get()` method you get the value of the `Cubetti`'s id value, which is set to `1`. That is why you get the value `1` for both `Uno` & `Due`.

**In the second case:**

 you place `setId()` in the `RGC` constructor. Here you basically set the id of the `Cubetti`'s ID. Thus calling the `getId()` the `id` of the `Cubetti` is being returned.