# this operator and private variable in inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, this, private

I have a class called **Parent** which has a private variable and a method named display to display that variable value. In a class called **Child** , parent is inherited.

```
    public class GoodDay {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Child().display();
        }
    }

    class Parent
    {
        private int i=5;
        public void display()
        {
            System.out.println(this.i +" "+this.getClass());
        }
    }

    class Child extends Parent
    { }
```

**Output** `5 class p1.Child`

1) `this.getClass()` gives `p1.Child` as the value. So this display method is a **inherited method copy** which is available in the Child class. Then how can it access the Parent class **private variable** without using public getter and setter?

2) Why **this** keyword in `this.i` doesn't give any error as there is no i in child class?

I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716335) and it says that even the private variables are available in the child class objects and not in child class. How and Why ?

Comment: `this` is not not an operator in `test.i`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does subclasses inherit private fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716040/does-subclasses-inherit-private-fields)

Comment: @DavidPostill i have already checked that question (I have also linked that in my question). It seems similar but i believe that I'm asking the question in a different perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Ok, the `display()` method is visible in the `Child` class due to the `public` access modifier. The instance variable `i` isn't accessible directly e.g. `new Child().i`, but it's perfectly fine to access it "via" a call to `display()` - this is by *intention of object oriented design*.

The purpose of access modifiers (there are four of them in java: `public`, `protected`, `package-private` and `private`) is to limit how and exactly where a member (such as an instance variable or a method) can be directly accessed. This promotes better design, through principles like `encapsulation`.

So just because an `int` is `private` doesn't mean it can't be accessed indirectly by another class - it only can't be accessed directly. If you expose your `int` to the outside world via a `public` method, that's completely fine, since the public method of a class can access all of the private members of the same class.

2) `this.i` doesn't give an error because it is referred to in the context of the `Parent` class (not `Child`).

By the way you can avoid `this.` in most cases. Try this, it's the same.

```
    System.out.println(i +" " + getClass());
```

And thirdly, why does it print `class p1.Child`, when the code executes from the `Parent` class? Simple, because `getClass()` is overloaded by every class, and via polymorphism and method overloading / dynamic dispatch you are executing the `getClass()` (and, via the print statement, implicitly the `toString()` method from that...) from the `Child`class.

Does this make things any clearer?

Comment: Thanks @vikingsteve. I got the 2 and 3 points. Can you please elaborate point 1. Especially "this is by intention of object oriented design." - this part.

Answer (score 0):

If `Child` doesn't override the `display()` method, because of polymorphism `super.display()` method, that is `Parent` `display()` method. If you want to access to `i` variable in `Child` class, you must declare `protected` this variable, instead of `private`.