# How is constructor being called without any instance associated with it?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor, super

Please see the below code:

```
class A {
    private int b;
    A(){
        b=5;
    }
}

class B extends A {

}

class C {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        B b=new B();
    }
}
```

When I create an instance of B,the default constructor of B invokes the constructor of A which assigns a value to instance variable b.
My query is since instance variables are associated with instances of classes, and we have not created any instance of class A,what does this assignment(b=5) really mean? Also what does the call to A's constructor really mean when there is no instance of A?

Comment: But there _is_ an instance of `A`.  It just happens to also be an instance of `B`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answering this question displays a lack of basic knowledge of OO principles and should be taught by reading a good tutorial since it's too broad to answer on SO. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 5):

`B extends A` means that an instance of `B` *is also* an instance of `A`, just like a dog is also an animal.  It's both at the same time, so it's perfectly normal for `b=5` to make sense, since the `B` is also an `A` and that is initializing the `b` field in `A`.

Comment: But b is private and hence is not inherited by class B

Comment: It doesn't matter if b is private. There may be public or protected methods that perform operations that include b in those operations. Therefore, even if it is not always obvious, all of A gets initialized when B is created.

Comment: B still has a b, it just can't see it; only its inherited A methods can see it.

Comment: But we never instantiated A,so where is b when there is no instance of A in memory?

Comment: @user3678484 Did you read my comment under the question?  Why do you keep asserting there is no instance of A in memory?

Comment: There _is_ an instance of `A` in memory.  It's the instance of `B`, which is also an `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716040/do-subclasses-inherit-private-fields) about class inheritance vs object inheritance in Java. According to [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2) you would say that class B doesn't inherit the private field b from class A.

> Members of a class that are declared private are not inherited by
>   subclasses of that class.

However an instance of B inherits all the data from A including the private field b.

Comment: so even without an instance of A in memory, the field b with value 5 is residing in memory?

Comment: do you mean an instance of B?

Comment: the instance variable b defined in class A.Is it present in memory even though there is no instance of A in memory?

Comment: when you instantiate B  private field b is also created in memory

Comment: ok.so private variables of superclass are not inherited by subclass but are inherited by instances of subclass? Is this statement correct?

Comment: Have you checked the link? When you talk about class inheritance then `does not inherit` means `is not visible/cannot be accessed`. When you talk about object inheritance it means that parent's fields are also created in memory (inherited).