# the right design approach for creating different User classes

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns

I am trying to create chat app that will have different users:simple user, vip users and etcetera.

all types of users will have the data that simple user have, like:name,password,email and so on however all the other users type have uniqe options only to them.

I thought to create class SimpleUser that will have the basic functionality that achieved by using private variables, getters/setters,and so on, while all other user types will have their own classes that extends the SimpleUser class and add their uniqe functionality.

but after I seen this article 
 [Do subclasses inherit private fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716040/do-subclasses-inherit-private-fields)  its just doesn't seems the right approach.

I am not sure that using Interface to provide optional functionality will help, because i still have private variabels in each user type that I access using getters/setters.

also currently I am cheking in every screen what the type of the user (in order to choose the rigth options for him), its seems clunky, is there a way to check the type of the user only once (when the user logs in) and in all screens simply use his uniqe functions?

- what is the correct way to design my classes?
- is their one solution for both my problems?

Comment: What kind of behavior will differ from simple and VIP users? Focus on modeling behaviors, not data.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps approach things from the other side, rather than think about user, perhaps think about screens, each user has a "level" and the screens provide the per level functionality, as really the functionality isn't really the users its the screens, the screen just decides based on the user.

I think I would stat with an enum with `Simple` `VIP` etc and this enum would have methods that do the appropriate thing for that level of user.

Comment: you right, but everyone have the same screens only some of functionlity change, and some of the fields appear/ disappear.

Comment: Then it strikes me the Screen is in charge, so, the if you have a Lobby screen it has knows how to draw itself for the logged in ```User```, determined on the user's "level", if the ```User``` has to understand how to control the ```Screen```, every new ```Screen``` you add to your chat program will cause a change to the ```User``` class.  You can have a config object ```LobbyConfig``` for example which can return the appropriate config for the users level.

Comment: you right, but everyone have the same screens only some of functionlity change, and some of the fields appear/ disappear. if i use Enum with methods how to confirm that only the "right" type of Enum can use the method? also from what I learned in OOP (maybe I misunderstood) its not the best approach to create Type(Class,Enum Etc.) that part of his objects(in our case Enums) never use some part of his functions.

Comment: A Enum represents a ```Level``` of usability, every physical user at a terminal will get there own instance of a ```Screen```, it will have a method, say ```init(Level level)``` this will call ```ScreenConfig.getConfig(Level level)``` returning a ```ScreenConfig``` that ```init``` can use to turn fields off and on.  Using types ensure correct access, there is no reason why a class can't have functionality that isn't always used, it is sometimes bad form to not implement everything when inheriting as this breaks the IS-A relationship, but sometimes it happens, I don't see that happening here.

Comment: thanks, I need to find the right way to to implement this in terms of Android usage.