# confused about inheritance in c++ (public and private)

Tags: c++, inheritance, encapsulation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std ;
enum COLOR { Green, Blue, White, Black, Brown } ;
class Animal {
public :
    Animal() : _name("unknown") {
        cout << "constructing Animal object "<< _name << endl ;
    }
    Animal(string n,COLOR c) : _name(n),_color(c) {
        cout << "constructing Animal object "<< _name << endl ;
    }

    ~Animal() {
        cout << "destructing Animal object "<< _name << endl ;
    }
    void speak() const {
        cout << "Animal speaks "<< endl ;
    }
    void move() const { }
private :
    string _name;
    COLOR _color ;
};
class Mammal:public Animal{
public:
    Mammal(string n,COLOR c):Animal(n,c){
        cout << "constructing Mammal object "<< _name << endl ;
    }
    ~Mammal() {
        cout << "destructing Animal object "<< _name << endl ;
    }
    void eat() const {
        cout << "Mammal eat " << endl ;
    }
};
```

I just started transitioning from java to C++ today, am practicing some object oriented coding to know the differences.

In the above code, I am unable to access _name from mammal class.

Does the mammal class not inherit private attributes? In this case, do I have to re-create those attributes for every inheritances?

Comment: Your title doesn't match your body - do you actually mean you're confused by inheritance in C++?

Comment: private is private. If you want the member variables to be visible from a derived class, put them in a ``protected`` section.

Comment: ... Or public. BTW - C++ does not have package protection

Comment: The private members are in there, but only the base class and its friends can see and use them. Sub classes can only see public and protected members.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do subclasses inherit private fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716040/do-subclasses-inherit-private-fields)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that you cannot access the private attributes of `Animal` from within `Mammal`. However, this isn't new if you're coming from Java - it works the same there.

See this link for an example: [Do subclasses inherit private fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716040/do-subclasses-inherit-private-fields)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access outside  private variable of  class, here _name is private scope variable of class . Derived class aslo cannot access private scope items from base . To solve this problem , you can declare _name as protected , it will accessed derived class .