# Using a method of parent class with variable of child class without overriding

Tags: java, inheritance, parent-child, parent, overriding

I am currently designing two classes in Java, and am having some trouble with understanding my current problem of inheritance, so I've created a simple example code in hopes that someone can help me understand what is going on.

So in this example, a parent class (for general purpose, we could call it class Car) and a child class (class RedCar). The parent class, which is abstract, contains an attribute distance, and contains a method of computeVelocity, which takes input argument time (double), and returns a double value of distance divided by time (thus giving velocity).

The child class has a constructor, RedCar(double inputDistance). It should also have access to the computeVelocity method, without overriding it.

Here's where the problem is. Logically, I understand that computeVelocity should not take the inputDistance variable from RedCar because its calling a method of another class. What I want to know, however, is how to bring that method into the RedCar class so that it could be used within said class with the arguments handed to the constructor.

Here is an example of the code

```
//Car Class
public abstract class Car{
  //abstract variable
  private double distance;
  //compute velocity method
  public double computeVelocity(double time){
     return distance/time;
  }
 }




 //RedCar Class
 public class RedCar extends Car{
   public double distance;

   public RedCar (double inputDistance){
      this.distance = inputDistance;
   }
  //This is currently my method but I believe this already constitutes as overridding
  public double computeVelocity(double hours){
      Car.super.computeVelocity(hours);
  }
 }
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do here, or why the method needs to be overridden at all.  Since the override doesn't add anything, why have it at all?  Why not just let the base class' `computeVelocity` method be used?

Comment: You shouldn't have a second distance field in the subclass. The distance field of the base class, by the way, is always 0. Just have a protected constructor in the base class taking distance as argument, and call it (using `super(distance)`) from the subclass constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in some of the comments to you answer, you don't really need and shouldn't have the distance twice (once in the parent class and once in the child class). Use the distance parameter from the parent class and there is no reason to override your method. You can call your parent class method using the `super` keyword.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since the private instance variable is inherited in the subclass but not accessible in subclass(You can use the reflection to access it). You have two way to provide value in Car instance variable private double distance by providing the public setter or getter method or provide the  protected or public constructor and call that constructor from the subclass.

See the link   [Do subclasses inherit private fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716040/do-subclasses-)   inherit-private-fields

Constructor in the super class which set the value in the private distance variable because private member only accessible by there own member means by their own method and constructor.

```
    protected Car(double distance){
     this.distance = distance;
     }
```

And also you have no need to define the distance variable again in the subclass because you are not using it in your method computeVelocity (of subclass). Since subclass method call the super class method and the super class method use own private double distance. So your distance variable define in subclass not used by the super class method.

After providing the protected constructor in super class you can call it from subclass constructor using the super keyword.The super keyword call the constructor of the super class. Since we  provide the  constructor  in super class so java not add any default constructor in super class. And calling that constructor from sub class using super assign the value in private double distance variable

```
     public RedCar(double inputDistance) {
     super(inputDistance);

      }
```

And correct way to call the super class method is, no need Car.super

```
    public double computeVelocity(double hours) {
      return super.computeVelocity(hours);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class `RedCar` inherits class `Car`. So `Car` is not just another class. If you create a `RedCar` instance, all parts of `Car` are also available. A `RedCar` **is a** `Car`.

In your solution you have created a field `distance` both in the super class and in the subclass. Actually you have two fields named `distance` in each `RedCar` instance.

Here comes the visibility into account. Though the private variable `distance` is part of `RedCar` it is only visible in class `Car`. If only methods defined in `Car` needs to access `distance` there is no need to change the visibility. But you need a way to set the `distance`. If the value doesn't change over time, you should include a constructor in class `Car`.

The visibility of method `computeVelocity()` defined in `Car` is public, so there is no need to repeat it in the subclass. Because a `RedCar` is a `Car` you can call `computeVelocity()` on each `RedCar` instance.

```
public abstract class Car{
  private double distance;

  // Constructor with visibility protected.
  // So it is visible in each subclass and must be 
  // called by each subclass constructor.
  // Btw.: It is common practice to use the same name
  // for input parameters as for fields. The field
  // variable can be accessed with the "this" keyword.
  protected Car(double distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
  }

  //compute velocity method
  public double computeVelocity(double time){
     return distance/time;
  }
}


public class RedCar extends Car{
  public double distance;

  public RedCar (double distance){
    // Call the Car constructor
    super(distance)
  }

  // No need to repeat the definition of 
  // computeVelocity unless you want to redefine 
  // the behaviour..
}
```

Then when you create a `RedCar` instance:

```
RedCar redCar = new RedCar(100.0);
```

first the `RedCar` constructor is called which then calls the `Car` constructor which sets the `distance` field to `100.0`.

You can call the method:

```
double velocity = redCar.computeVelocity(60.0);
```