# How do I use the a private instance variable in a superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass, super

I am currently learning about inheritance in my java class. And I can't figure out why I can't use the variable "ID" using super in my subclass. What is wrong with my constructor for the savings class? Also I am not allowed to change the instance variables in account to public.

```
     public class Account
{
private String ID;
private double balance;
private int deposits;
private int withdrawals;
private double service;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Account
 */
public Account(String IDNumber, double cashBalance)
{
    ID = IDNumber;
    balance = cashBalance;
    deposits = 0;
    withdrawals = 0;
    service = 0;
}
```

I get the error "ID has private access in Account"

```
    public class Savings extends Account
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private boolean active;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Savings
 */
public Savings(String IDNumber, double cashBalance)
{
    super(ID);
    super(balance);
    active = null;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4716040

Comment: `super(...)` doesn't mean "set this instance variable from the superclass"; it means "call a specific superclass constructor, passing these arguments".

Comment: Private has meaning-the JLS explains all of this in great detail. Nutshell is that private means absolutely that: it's private. And in your example ID doesn't even have a value anyway, so calling a super constructor that doesn't exist with a value that isn't accessible makes little to no sense.

Answer (score 2):

`super()` calls the constructor for the parent class. It has nothing to do with the private variable for that class.

I think you ment to do:

```
super(IDNumber, cashBalance);
```

This calls the constructor for the parent class, passing the same variables `Savings` was created with to the `Account` class.

Note that from within the class `Savings` you will not be able to access the parent variables. You have to change the access to `protected` for this. `protected` allows the class itself, and children access, whereas `private` only allows the class itself access.

Comment: @ChristophT Please accept my answer so the correct answer will be easily identifiable for others.

Comment: Asking to accept after 5 minutes is a little but early. Although unlikely, there is always a certain chance that something else comes in that would help even more...

Comment: @GhostCat No problem. Glad it solved your problem. Good luck with Java :)

Comment: I didn't ask the question. You may want to pay a little bit more of attention whom you are talking with.

Comment: @GhostCat Lol, sorry. Your nicks looked so similiar at a quick glance