# Override variable with subclass type

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have a class that has a listener interface. I want to create a subclass with the listener interface being a subclass type. For example:

```
interface OnSadListener {
    void imSad();
}

interface OnCryingListener extends OnSadListener {
    void imCrying();
}

class Person {
    OnSadListener listener;

    void setListener(OnSadListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}

class Baby extends Person {
    OnCryingListener listener; // I want it to override the original one in Person

    void cry(){
        listener.imSad();
        listener.imCrying();
    }
}

void doIt(){
    Baby michael = new Baby();

    michael.setListener(new OnCryingListener() {
        @Override void imSad(){
            System.out.print("I'm sad");
        }

        @Override void imCrying(){
            System.out.print("Wahhhhhh!");
        }
    });

    michael.cry(); // the imCrying funtion is empty (setListener setted Person's listener and not Baby's)
}
```

I know `Baby.setListener(new OnCryingListener(){...});` would work because OnCryingListener is a subclass of OnSadListener. But then I would not be able to call `imCrying()` or it would be empty.

Is there a way for `OnCryingListener listener` to "override" `Person`'s `OnSadListener listener`?

Comment: an interface `extends` an other interface.

Comment: @CodeMatrix typing error, changed :)

Comment: When `Baby.cry()` is called, the listener is never set...

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl That's what I'm trying to find a solution for. If `Baby.listener` was "overriding" `Person.listener`, when `Baby.setListener()` is called `Baby.listener` would be set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716040/do-subclasses-inherit-private-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the `setListener(OnSadListener)` method in the `Baby` class, because you are never setting the listener.

```
class Baby extends Person {
    OnCryingListener listener;

    @Override
    void setListener(OnSadListener listener) {
        this.listener = (OnCryingListener) listener;
    }

    void cry() {
        listener.imSad();
        listener.imCrying();
    }
}
```

---

A more complete example is the following...

```
class Person {
    protected OnSadListener listener; // Make it protected or add accessor/mutators

    void setListener(OnSadListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

By making the `listener` protected, you can reuse the `Person` class' `OnSadListener`. You just need to cast the listener to a `OnCryingListener` to call the `imCrying()` method.

```
class Baby extends Person {
    @Override
    void setListener(OnSadListener listener) {
        this.listener = (OnCryingListener) listener;
    }

    void cry() {
        listener.imSad();
        ((OnCryingListener) listener).imCrying(); // Cast here
    }
}
```

---

### Update

If you want to use generics, you can remove the need for casting.

```
public class Person <T extends OnSadListener> {
    protected T listener;

    public void setListener(T listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

Now you can tell `Baby` what type of listener is is dealing with.

```
public class Baby extends Person<OnCryingListener> {
    @Override
    public void setListener(OnCryingListener listener) {
        this.listener = (OnCryingListener) listener;
    }

    public void cry() {
        listener.imSad();
        listener.imCrying(); // No need to cast
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm marking this as correct. Anyway, will `((OnCryingListener) listener).imCrying();` work? I thought of doing that but I assumed once I saved the `OnCryingListener` into the `OnSadListener` field I wouldn't be able to access `imCrying()` again, it being "deleted".

Comment: Furthermore, if I call `Baby.setListener()` from somewhere else it will ask me for a `OnSadListener` and not a `OnCryingListener`...

Comment: @IakaNoe Your `Baby` class originally typed it as an `OnCryingListener`, so you would have needed to pass one in anyways. Since `OnSadListener ` is the parent, it is OK to use it as such when referring to a `Baby`.

Comment: @IakaNoe You allowed to pass a sub-class into a method that expects its parent. This is called IOC (Inversion of Control).

Comment: I know that. What I suspect is that I will lose the methods that the subclass implements by casting it to its parent type.

Answer (score 0):

Fields are NOT "overridden" in Java. Only methods are overridden.

Since you assume that fields are overridden, in this example you are expecting only one `listener` field to exist in a `Baby` object. And you are expecting that single field to be set when you call `michael.setListener()`.

But in reality, there are 2 fields in a `Baby` object. When you call `michael.setListener()`, only the field declared in `Person` class is set.

Comment: I already knew that, yet I'm asking if there is a way to **achieve that same result**: having only one `listener` in a `Baby` object and it being set by `Baby.setListener()`.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this by simply removing the `listener` field from `Baby`. And only have a `listener` field in `Person`.